# Prove that: $(a^5-2a+4)(b^5-2b+4)(c^5-2c+4)\ge9(ab+bc+ca)$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw, tangent-line-method

Let $a,b,c>0$ satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$ . Prove that: $$(a^5-2a+4)(b^5-2b+4)(c^5-2c+4)\ge9(ab+bc+ca)$$
My idea is to use a well-known inequality (We can prove by Schur) $$(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)\ge 9(ab+bc+ca)$$ and the problem is prove  $$(a^5-2a+4)(b^5-2b+4)(c^5-2c+4)\ge(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)$$
Anyone have a better idea ? please help me

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cleft%28a%5E%7B2%7D-2a%2B4%5Cright%29%5Cleft%28b%5E%7B2%7D-2b%2B4%5Cright%29%5Cleft%28c%5E%7B2%7D-2c%2B4%5Cright%29+-+%5Cleft%28a%5E%7B2%7D%2B2%5Cright%29%5Cleft%28b%5E%7B2%7D%2B2%5Cright%29%5Cleft%28c%5E%7B2%7D%2B2%5Cright%29+minimum+when+a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%3D3) says that you can replace $a^5, b^5, c^5$ with $a^2, b^2, c^2$ and the inequality still holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way: use uvw https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/uvw/info

Since $a^5-2a+4\geq4a^2-5a+4,$ it's enough to prove that:
$$\prod_{cyc}(4a^2-5a+4)\geq9(ab+ac+bc),$$ which is $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where $f$ increases. I got here:
$$f'(w^3)=128w^3+684u+115-240v^2>0.$$

Thus, it's enough to prove the last inequality in two cases:

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$;
2. Two variables are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Since $ab+ac+bc\leq a^2+b^2+c^2=3,$ it's enough to prove that:
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^5-2a+4)\geq27$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\ln(a^5-2a+4)-\ln3\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\ln(a^5-2a+4)-\ln3-\frac{1}{2}(a^2-1)\right)\geq0.$$
Now, prove that $$\ln(a^5-2a+4)-\ln3-\frac{1}{2}(a^2-1)\geq0$$ for any $0<a<\sqrt3$.

Comment: Do you have a method that does not use logarithms ?

Comment: @SUWG Yes, I see another way, but it's not so nice.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to do that? Or you can say the basics, I'll try to prove it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping me, I also have a solution after many days of thinking
$$[9(ab+bc+ca)]^2=27(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)^2$$
By AM-GM, we have:
$$27(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)(ab+bc+ca)\le(a+b+c)^6$$
$$\to 9(ab+bc+ca)\le(a+b+c)^3 $$
The problem is:
$$(a^5-2a+4)(b^5-2b+4)(c^5-2c+4)\ge(a+b+c)^3$$
By AM-GM, we have:
$$a^5-2a+4=\frac{1}{5}(a^5+a^5+1+1+1)-2a+1+\frac{1}{5}(a^5+a^5+a^5+1+1+10)\geq (a-1)^2+\frac{1}{5}(5a^3+10)\geq a^3+2$$
$$\to (a^5-2a+4)(b^5-2b+4)(c^5-2c+4) \ge (a^3+2)(b^3+2)(c^3+2) $$
The problem is:
$$(a^3+2)(b^3+2)(c^3+2) \ge (a+b+c)^3 $$
Which is true by Holder